# How to handle missing data in split?

Tags: python, pattern-matching

I want to split a string where a part may be missing.
E.g., `"foo-bar"` should be split into `"foo"` and `"bar"` while `"zot"` into `"zot"` and `None`.

```
foo,bar = line.split('-',1)
```

works for the first case but not for the second one:

```
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I can go, of course, the long way:

```
foobar = line.split('-',1)
if len(foobar) == 2:
    foo,bar = foobar
else:
    foo,bar = foobar[0],None
```

but I wonder if this is the most "pythonic" way.

Comment: There are many other options: `try: except ValueError`, `if '-' in line`, ... Are lines missing `'-'` exceptional?

Comment: Your `else` would have to be `foo, bar = line, None` or `foo, bar = foobar[0], None`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Catch the exception:

```
try:
    foo, bar = line.split('-', 1)
except ValueError:
    # not enough values
    foo, bar = line, None
```

Note that you'd need to split *once* to get two values, not two times.

Answer (score 2):

For this exact example, I'd use the  [`partition`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) method.

```
>>> 'foo-bar'.partition('-')
('foo', '-', 'bar')
>>> 'foobar'.partition('-')
('foobar', '', '')
>>> 'foo-bar-baz'.partition('-')
('foo', '-', 'bar-baz')
```

For the general case where there's more than one split, but still a known number, I usually check the length of the result of `split`, but Martijn is (unsurprisingly) right that catching the exception is fine too and is probably a better choice if strings missing the delimiter are uncommon.

Comment: Note that you then have to unpack `foo, _, bar = ...`

Comment: This requires a different unpack and even then doesn't assign `None` to `bar`: `foo, _, bar = line.partition('-')`. The `None` issue is exactly why I didn't use this.

Answer (score 0):

using list Comprehension:

```
i=['ff-bb','cc','dd-ss-vv']

[string+[None] if len(string)==1 else string for string in [x.split('-') for x in i]]
```

returns

```
 [['ff', 'bb'], ['cc', None], ['dd', 'ss', 'vv']]
```